# Can't load API using Proxy

Tags: javascript, html, json

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
            let lat;
            let long;
            
            if(navigator.geolocation){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)  =>{
                    lat=position.coords.latitude;
                    long=position.coords.longitude;
                   // console.log(position);
                const proxy= 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
                const api= '${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/d5906bb943a9972ceca80788517a44bc/${lat},${long}';

                fetch(api)
                  .then(response =>{
                      return response.json();
                  })
                  .then(data =>{
                      console.log(data);
                  });
                });

            }
            else{
                h1.textContent="hey please allow this app to access your location";
            }
        });
```

```css
  *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body{
                height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
                background: linear-gradient(rgb(62, 101, 119),rgb(36, 35, 35));
            }
            .time,.temperature{
                height: 30vh;
                width: 50%;
                justify-content: space-around;
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
            }
            .temperature{
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            .degree-section{
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .degree-section h2{
                font-size: 30px;
            }
            .degree-section span{
                font-size: 20px;
                margin: 0.3cm;
            }
```

```html
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Weather Forecast</title>      
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="time">
            <h2>TimeZone</h2>
            <p>Icon</p>
        </div>
        <div class="temperature">
            <div class="degree-section">
                <h2 class="value">34</h2>
                <span class="fah">F</span>
            </div>
            <div class="temperature-description">its cold</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code i am trying to create a weather app and for that i am using an API and a proxy to go around the course error but i am getting following error:

**weather.html:71 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/javascript_projects/$%7Bproxy%7Dhttps://api.darksky.net/forecast/d5906bb943a9972ceca80788517a44bc/$%7Blat%7D,$%7Blong%7D 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ weather.html:71


weather.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ weather.html:75**

I don't know to overcome it ...can someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building your request URL with a string:

```
const proxy= 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
                const api= '${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/d5906bb943a9972ceca80788517a44bc/${lat},${long}';
```

In order for the placeholders to work, you should be using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const proxy= 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
                const api= `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/d5906bb943a9972ceca80788517a44bc/${lat},${long}`;
```

Note the change from `'` to ``` in the definition of the `api` constant.

Comment: Usually, the hardest to spot. Glad to help!